# Как создать нейронную сеть с помощью библиотеки fann?

Tags: java, fann

Как реализовать создание нейронной сети (500 входных нейронов, 400 на скрытом слое и 10 на выходном)?

Не тренировку, а сам процесс, т.е. как создание и запуск нейронной сети.

В частности интересует, что значит путь в строке `Fann fann = new Fann("/path/to/file")` в офиц. документации.

Comment: внимательно посмотрите на JavaDoc, в частности на описание конструктора, где такой конструктор говорит "Load an existing FANN definition from a file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

внимательно посмотрите на JavaDoc, в частности на описание конструктора, где такой конструктор говорит "Load an existing FANN definition from a file".

На самом деле внутри конструктора вызывается нативный код

```
  native Pointer fann_create_from_file(
        String configuration_file);
```

Исходя из [этой](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_io-h.html#fann_create_from_file) документации,  данный конструктор принимает файл который был сохранен методом `fann_save`.

То есть вы создаете свою модель, обучаете, и чтобы вам на следующий день не тратить время на обучение, вы можете сохранять данные весов и использовать их в следующий раз для корректировки. Для этого используете метод fann_save.  А `new Fann("/path/to/file")` выгружает уже сохраненные данные.